# Adding where clause to index method of scaffolded controller ASP.NET MVC with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a project model and an actors model - a project can contain multiple actors. I'm trying to modify the scaffolded views for my actors controller so that an id is passed in to the index and create method, so that only actors for the current project can be seen (index) or added (create).

Here is what I start with for the index method and I'm not sure where I need to add the where clause. N.B. I will be passing in id as a parameter to index from the URL.

(Sorry this is such a basic question, I've been googling but can't find an answer).

Thanks!

```
private JustSpecItAppContext db = new JustSpecItAppContext();

// GET: Actors1
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Actors.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: `public ActionResult Index(int id)` and `return View(db.Actors.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList());` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
public ActionResult Index(int actorId)
    {
        return View(db.Actors.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == actorId));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DotNetIsMyPower but I already implemented Ben's response above which did the job. I am reading about FirstOrDefault now though to see if that might be useful

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will be faster in compare to Where clause,

Let say you have 1 lac records in your table, and your actor Id is 10.

if you're using db.Actors.Where(x => x.Id == id) then it will go through all the records to match the condition (even if its found the match at rec 10).
if you're using db.Actors.FirstOrDefault(a => a.id == actorId) then it won't go through all the records, once it match the condition id == actorId, it will return that record, withough going through all the records.

Comment: But if you're expecting multiple matching records, then you should use Where clause.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - this is good to know :-) I am only expecting one record to be returned, so this option is better (though both responses do answer my original question). This has been good learning, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@gazrolo4, there are a number of ways of implementing what you asked. You can try them for learning purposes maybe:
Here is one way:-

```
private JustSpecItAppContext db = new JustSpecItAppContext();

// GET: Actors1
    public ActionResult Index(int actorId)
    {
        var query= db.Actors.Where(x => x.Id == actorId).ToList())

        return View(query);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to change actors to query.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Robinson's response above worked for what I needed. Thanks for the help guys.